# 3n + 1 failed for unknown reason

Tags: java

I am doing the programming challenges of which I am doing the 3n + 1 challenge. I ahve completed code for it and it works fine for me completely BUT on the website it keeps saying that I have the wrong answer.I have no idea why if anyone can give me a reason for this it would be a great help. Code is below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Conjecture {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int array[] = new int[8];
        int finalCounter = 0;
        int currentCounter = 0;

        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(
                    new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt")));

            int counter = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                array[counter] = scanner.nextInt();
                counter++;
            }
        } finally {
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
                System.out.println("done");
            }
        }

        for (int loop = 0; loop < array.length; loop += 2) {
            int i = array[loop];
            int j = array[loop + 1];
            finalCounter = 0;
            for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
                int x = k;
                currentCounter = 0;
                while (x != 1) {

                    if (x % 2 == 0) {
                        x = x / 2;
                        currentCounter++;
                    } else if (x % 2 == 1) {

                        x = x * 3 + 1;
                        currentCounter++;
                    }

                    if (currentCounter > finalCounter) {
                        finalCounter = currentCounter;
                    }

                }

            }
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + (finalCounter + 1));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading from `file.txt`, you should read the input from `System.in`. Since the [problem statement](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110101&format=html) does not says the number of test cases, you should process each case at the moment of reading the case. Your array is just 8 elements long, and I'm pretty sure there is going to be more test cases.